# "Can't make item 0 of list of <<script>> into type text" error

Tags: applescript

Just started learning applescript today, and I'm getting the following error when trying to pull a string from a list:

> error "Cant make item 0 of list my_list of <> into type text."
>   number -1700 from item 0 of my_list to text

I'm not sure what it means.  The error comes from these lines:

```
set my_list to {"http://my_url.com?var=a" as text}
set theUrl to (item 0 in my_list) as text
```

I've looked around, and can't seem to find anything that indicates I am doing this incorrectly.  What am I doing wrong?  I have also tried instantiating the list with more strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've done too much programming!  :-)  It turns out that AppleScript lists are *1*-indexed, and *not* 0-indexed.  So `item 1 in my_list` will work fine.  (AppleScript was designed to be used by non-programmers, so it has quirks like that.)

Also (at least on my 10.8.2 system), the class of `"strings"` is already `text`, so the `as text`s are unnecessary.  And just FYI, you can use `item 1 of …` instead of `item 1 in …`.  (See above re. "used by non-programmers:" it was supposed to look like English.)

Thus:

```
set my_list to {"http://my_url.com?var=a"}
set theUrl to item 1 in my_list
```

Or, if `my_list` is actually of unknown provenance and you do need to convert the result of the lookup,

```
set my_list to {"http://my_url.com?var=a"}
set theUrl to item 1 in my_list as text
```

(No parentheses are necessary on the last line.)

Comment: Ahhhh I see!  Thank you for the additional comments about the `as text` lines.  I originally had what you said above, but in my frustration I added casting calls everywhere, and changed "of" to "in".  As an aside, I think its dumb for a scripting language to be targeted towards non-programmers.  Users who go on to program after using applescript will be so confused now.